# How do I transfer CPP code into Linux-service?

Tags: c++, linux, services

I am Building an agent in C++ that alerts me if anyone has entered a USB on Linux-based computers.

When I'll finish, I need it to run the code on few Linux-based computers as a service.

How do I transfer my c++ code into a Linux service and make sure the code running all the time?

Comment: Look up [systemd services](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd/Services), you can provide an installer that sets up the service.

Comment: @Devolus: It's still a reasonable tag - you _can_ add extra systemd functionality using its C interface. I think it's on-topic here; however it appears that the question would have benefitted from basic research.

Comment: @MSalters, you are right, but the question is rather vague. It took it that the OP just want to install his program as a service, but it's not clear from the question if this is the only thing he needs.

Comment: Execute the compiled binary in startup commands. I think it's somewhere at `/etc/init.d`

Comment: Most Linux distros did away with `init.d` ***YEARS ago***.  I can't imagine who +1 that init.d comment.  `systemctl` has replaced it and uses a completely different system. You will need to make a <program_name>.ini file to launch your app and use the `systemctl` command to register it. Be advised that there are WARS in the linux community over this switch but it has happened weather people like it or not.